# axios request didn't work ! not found message always shows

Tags: reactjs, axios, charles-proxy

```
 import React from 'react';
 import {Component} from 'react';
 import {Fragment} from 'react';
 import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

 import axios from 'axios';

 class TodoList extends Component{
        constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            inputValue:'hello there',
            list:[]
        };
        this.inputValueChange=this.inputValueChange.bind(this);  
        this.addList=this.addList.bind(this); 
        this.delList=this.delList.bind(this);
    }
  
    render(){
        return(
        <Fragment>
            <input 
                value={this.state.inputValue}
                onChange={this.inputValueChange} 
                ref={(input)=>{this.input=input}}      
            />
            <button onClick={this.addList}>按鈕</button>
            <ul>
                {this.getTodoItem()}               
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
        );
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('/test/todolist')
        .then(()=>{alert('successful')})
        .catch(()=>{alert('error')});
    }
```

---

I don't know what's wrong with Axios request.

After I refreshed page,I always got 'xhr.js:184 GET http://localhost:3000/test/todolist 404 (Not
Found)' message from console of development tool.

I understand this message means this file can not be found.

and I discovered Charles proxy tool didn't show the url of localhost.

So I thought maybe the setting of Charles proxy made some problems.

The procedure of setting Charles proxy tool I have done:

(1) check “Proxy” -> “Windows proxy”

(2) Help ->SSL Proxying ->Install Charles Root Certificate

(3) Proxy -> SSL Proxying Settings -> check 'enable SSL proxy' -> add Location ->
setting Host as *, Post as 443

(4) extend SwitchySharp -> setting name as Charles -> setting manual configuration http proxy as
10.0.0.143(Charles proxy tool help -> local IP address),port as 8888(Charles proxy port) ->
save

(5) check charles on browser navbar

(6) Tools -> Map local -> check enable map local -> add location as
http://localhost/test/todolist, local path as C:\Users\user\Desktop\todolist.json

By the way,my computer is using windows system,and I am using Microsoft Edge as development environment and Charles proxy version is 4.5.6

After I tried,the problem still exist.

I hope someone can point out what exact problem is and suggest some useful solutions.

very very appreciate ^^

Answer (score 1):

By default, all of Axios's traffic does not go through Proxy. Therefore, your Map Local Directory doesn't work and you get 404 Not found.

To fix it, you might explicitly tell Axios to use Proxy at a certain host and port (Please replace host and port with real value from Charles Proxy)

```js
axios.get({
  url: '/test/todolist',

  // 'proxy' defines the hostname and port of the proxy server
  // Use `false` to disable proxies, ignoring environment variables.
  // `auth` indicates that HTTP Basic auth should be used to connect to the proxy, and
  // supplies credentials.
  // This will set an `Proxy-Authorization` header, overwriting any existing
  // `Proxy-Authorization` custom headers you have set using `headers`.
  proxy: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 9090
  }
});
```

This problem also happens with cURL, fetch, ktor, .... [Read more](https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/couldnt-see-any-requests-from-3rd-party-network-libraries)